# Yii2 : Active Record add Not In condition

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

What is the active Record way of adding IN condition to an active Query
in yii 1.x you could use CDbCriteria like this

```
$cr = new CDbCriteria();
$cr->addNotInCondition('attribute', $array);
```

There seem to be no equivalent API call in yii2 active record implementation, how to do this via active record ?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041546/how-to-use-not-equal-to-inside-a-yii2-query/32860991#32860991) may help someone.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Well all query operands seems now merged within in `yii\db\QueryInterface::Where()` per documentation 
an In condition can now be added using something like

```
$query = MyModel::find()->where(['attribute'=>$array]);
```

for a not In condition it is slightly different format

```
$query = MyModel::find()->where(['not in','attribute',$array]);
```

Comment: This will fail, we need: $query = MyModel::find()->where(['attribute'=>$array])->all();

Comment: that would be for an in condition, the question is about not in refer here for details: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail

Comment: what is `$array` in the query ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$query = MyModel::findAll(['not in ','attribute',$array]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Comment: blank space in 'not in ' is surplus

Answer (score 3):

For numbers:

```
$query = MyModel::find()->where('NOT IN('.implode(',', $array).')');
```

For strings

```
$deleteContracts = Contract::find()
    ->where([
        'session_id' => $session_id,
        'status' => Contract::STATUS_COMPLETED
    ])
    ->andWhere(['not in', 'contract_id', $contracts])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the only working solution was :

```
$query = MyModel::find()->where('`your-attribute` NOT IN(' . implode(',', $array) . ')')->all();
```