# How to use not equal to inside a Yii2 query

Tags: yii2

I want to use a `yii2` query in which I want to check a not equal to condition.

I tried like this but it didn't give the desired results. How do I do it?

```
$details =  MovieShows::find()
   ->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
   ->andWhere(['location_id'=>$loc_id])
   ->andWhere(['cancel_date'=>!$date])
   ->all();
```

Comment: Why not to just look at the docs instead of such guessing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32089897/2559712

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In this case you need to use *operator format*: `[operator, operand1, operand2, ...]`. So your code should look like this:

```
$details = MovieShows::find()
           ->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
           ->andWhere(['location_id'=>$loc_id])
           ->andWhere(['<>','cancel_date', $date])
           ->all();
```

[More](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) about using where method and operator format

Comment: You can also use `!=` as "not equal" operator.

Answer (score 23):

You can also try this:

```
$details = MovieShows::find()->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
           ->andWhere(['!=', 'cancel_date', $date])->all();
```

for Greater than

```
$details = MovieShows::find()->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
               ->andWhere(['>', 'cancel_date', $date])->all();
```

for less than

```
$details = MovieShows::find()->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
               ->andWhere(['<', 'cancel_date', $date])->all();
```

[More](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) check here

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this one help...:)

```
$query->andFilterWhere([ 'or',
                           ['<=', 'affidavit_cont', 0],
                           ['=', 'affidavit_cont1', 0],
                           ['>', 'affidavit_cont2', 0],
                           ['!=', 'affidavit_cont3', $this->affidavit3],
                           ['in', 'attempt_count', $this->attempted],

                      ]);

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'job_invoice.paid_status', '',]);

$query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'status_id', $this->status_id]);

$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'last_attempt',
    strtotime(Utility::convertDate2Db($this->from_date)),
    strtotime(Utility::convertDate2Db($this->to_date))
    ]);
```

Comment: I've never seen it done quite like this, but really like it. Upvote :)

Answer (score 5):

The better and safe way to apply a condition.

```
Booking::find()->where('tour_id = :tour_id and id != :id', ['tour_id'=> $chk->tour_id, 'id' => $id])->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
$this->find()->where(['resource_id' => $resource_id]) ->andWhere(['>=', 'start_time', $start_time])->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addiction to the @tony answer, for those who need to encapsulate a **subquery** here there's a quick example:

```
$users = User::find()                  
            ->where([
                'not in',
                'id',
                (new Query())
                    ->select('user_id')
                    ->from(MyTable::tableName())
                    ->where(['related_id'=>$myRelatedId])
            ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->dropDownList(
     ArrayHelper::map(user::find()->where([ 
        'not in ' ,
        'first_name', 
        patient::find()
           ->select([ 'patient_name' ])
           ->asArray()  
     ])
     ->all(),'id','first_name')
```

Maybe it help you for whom need to use **subquery** .

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the below pasted code:

```
$details = MovieShows::find()->where(['movie_id'=>$id])
             ->andWhere(['location_id'=>$loc_id])
            ->andWhere(['not in','cancel_date',$date])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reading this needs to use a REGEXP or similar, this works in Yii2 (2.0.15.1):

`->andWhere(['NOT REGEXP', 'column','[A-Za-z]'])`