# how to build query like `select ... where id % 2 = 1` using Yii 2 ？

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Surely, I can `Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->query()`,
but what if I wanna use a `ActiveRecord::find()->where($conditions)` to do this job ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one of the options with using `yii\db\Expression`:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

$models = Customer::find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', ...])
    ->where(new Expression('id % 2 = 1')])
    ->all();
```

It's definetely better than raw sql and `['%2=', 'id', 1]` because it follows the order and more readable in my opinion.

`['%2=', 'id', 1]` also is not suitable here because `%2=` is not actually an operator like `not in` or `like` for example, so operator, value and `=` sign are kind of mixed together.

**Official docs:**

- [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html)

**Update:** I asked **samdark**, one of the main framework contributors in official Gitter chat and he said that the right way to do it is using `yii\db\Expression`.

Comment: When an Expression object is embedded within a SQL statement or fragment, it will be replaced with the $expression property value `without any DB escaping or quoting`. for now, I understand it's meaning.

Comment: but object (new Expression) can not be a key in an array. it works like this: `->where( new Expression('id % 2 = 1') )`

Comment: By this way, `where( new Expression('id % 2 = 1')` works as same as `where('id % 2 = 1')`. lol.

Comment: Sorry, expressions are more suitable for array values. Yes, so you can use first option suggested by @ıɹnʇɐɹʇıʞuɐ.

Comment: @haoliang I asked samdark just to be sure, the right way to write such conditions is via `yii\db\Expression`.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using Active Query too. This may help.

```
$customers = Customer::find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', ...])
    ->where('id % 2 = 1')
    ->all();
```

or

```
$customers = Customer::find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', ...])
    ->where(['% 2 =', 'id', 1])
    ->all();
```

[Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#dynamic-relational-query).

Comment: oh, Yii treats the first element as an operator between 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: @haoliang It's desribed in the official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) class [where()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#$where-detail), your `$conditions` will be `('id % 2 = 1')`.

Comment: Why the `switch` is needed here?

Comment: @arogachev it is not needed, it is an example and it makes the query easier to read in case the user does not prefer using `$conditions` variable.

Comment: `$conditions` variable is rarely needed actually. Instead you can have `$query` variable and conditionally add different parts of the query.